# NetBeans can’t be opened because the identity of the developer cannot be confirmed

Tags: netbeans

I was trying to install Netbeans on my Mac but it gives me this error:

> NetBeans 8.0.1 with JDK 8 Update 20.mpkg" can’t be opened because the identity of the developer cannot be confirmed.

Any idea on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Also, to solve your problem: System Preferences > Security & Privacy > click the lock icon in the lower left corner of the window to permit installation.

Answer (score 3):

You can override your OS security settings in your system preferences to open it.

https://netbeans.org/projects/www/lists/netcat/archive/2014-09/message/23

System Preferences > Security & Privacy > General

You will see a message:

"NetBeans 8.0.1.mpkg" was blocked from opening because the identity of the developer cannot be confirmed.

You have to click the lock icon at the bottom of your preferences window, in order to make changes.

Then select the "Anywhere" radio button for the "Allow apps downloaded from:" option.

Then you'll be able to open the NetBeans installer. Then, after installing, go back and change your preference back to the default.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently [an open bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26166681/netbeans-can-t-be-opened-because-the-identity-of-the-developer-cannot-be-confirm).

To work around the bug, change your security settings to "Allow apps downloaded from anywhere", and run the installer. Once installation is complete, you can revert your security settings and run NBIDE normally.